# How to change Ubuntu 18.04 login screen theme

Tags: login, themes

I am not satisfied with the default Ubuntu look and replaced it with Adapta GTK theme, Papirus icon theme and Breeze cursor theme (like in Manjaro Linux), so it looks good now (at least for me). But the login screen still looks like Ubuntu... So, my question is: **How to change login screen GTK theme to Adapta, login screen icon theme to Papirus and login screen cursor theme to Breeze**?
Maybe some instructions...

I have found here at Askubuntu (sorry can't remember links and authors) how to change the GTK theme of the login screen to Adapta, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not (although it worked for me):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css gdm3.css /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/gdm3-Adapta-Nokto.css 1
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css

cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/
if ! [[ -h gnome-shell-theme.gresource ]];
then
    sudo mv gnome-shell-theme.gresource gnome-shell-theme.gresource.original;
fi
sudo ln -frs /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource gnome-shell-theme.gresource

cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
sudo mv ubuntu.css ubuntu.css.original
sudo ln -s /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css ubuntu.css
```

Then reboot.